# iOS, Android, Mobile Phone: how to open a file in an editor?

Tags: android, ios, windows-phone

We would like to create an mobile app, where user will be presented with some downloaded document (word, excel, plain text etc.). Provided that the user will have some appropriate editor installed, how our app can use that editor and than, upon the closing of the editor, "force" the user to go back to our app?

Could somebody provide examples for all listed platforms? iOS, Android, Windows phone.

Comment: in Android implementation go to [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22556029/want-to-open-downloaded-file-in-appropriate-application-in-android/22556243#22556243)

Comment: @SimplePlan Thanks, it looks promising.

Comment: @OP yo welcome champ!

Answer (score 2):

For iOS you can use  UIDocumentInteractionController to open these files.

Comment: Could you provide some example?

Comment: here is a good tutorial for this ... http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-previewing-and-opening-documents--mobile-15130